# extract data from a matrix, maintaining NaNs as NaNs matlab

Tags: matlab, extract, nan

I have a dataset called 'data' of size 106*103*100. I am extracting a portion of the dataset for further analysis based on its geographical position using latitudes and longitudes and naming the extracted data 'testdata'). 'data' contains a mixture of both numbers and NaNs.

The data I want to extract lies within the latitudinal and longitudinal bounds of ylat_south=44,ylat_north=55,xlon_west=16 and xlon_east=30;

The matrix of latitudes is called: final_lat (106*103);
The matrix of longitudes is called: final_lon (106*103);
This is what I have to extract the data:

```
for i=1:size(data,3);
testdata(:,:,i)=+(final_lat>=ylat_south & final_lat<=ylat_north & 
final_lon>=xlon_west & final_lon<=xlon_east).*data(:,:,i);      
end
```

The code I have works (i.e. I end up with testdata of size 106*103*100), except, when testdata is written out, any cells that contained a NaN in 'data' are being written as a zero is the new 'testdata' matrix'. I know I could do this is a loop, with an if statement, but I am trying to keep the code as efficient as possible.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: after your code you can add the nan back with testdata(isnan(data(:)))=NaN

Comment: @LuisMendo It is in 2014b!

Comment: the '+' is being used to convert the logical array to a numerical one. @ASantosRibeiro thanks for that. I'm having a further issue perhaps you could help with. The data outside of the bounds also contains numbers and NaNs, the numbers of which are being replaced by zeros with the dot multiplication used above. I also want these zeros to be NaNs. However, I do not want to simply replace the zeros with NaNs, as it is possible that the data values could be zeros also. Can I index/select all the values outside of the range specified by the criteria, to replace numbers with NaNs?

Comment: @LuisMendo I know. But i+=2 doesnt work " `Did you mean i=i+2`" , however the other one works.

Comment: @LuisMendo Opps. You are rigth. Then I shoudl have done something wrong testing.... Probably overwrite some existing variable with the bad luck of getting the result I was expecting, I donk kwon! My bad. I was a bit astonished it worked hehe. x=+2 returns x with value +2

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question but testdata(isnan(data(:)))=NaN changes every index in testdata that was NaN in data, back to nan. So it does not matter whether they are inside or outside of the bounds. every nan in data will be in testdata

Comment: what you suggested works. Thanks. I was confusing myself with the data. Thanks @ASantosRibeiro